# VBA group rows and convert number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data where each two rows is its own individual group of data (ex: row4&5 go together, 6&7, and so on.)

For each group, one of the cells in the column currently has data stored, but there is not a pattern to where the data is stored, such as odd/even numbered rows.

I am working on a code that will, for each group, find the cell holding the value, convert it to a positive number (as all the data are negative numbers), and append that number into the blank cell within the group.

I hope this makes sense. Below is the code that I have built so far, but as of now, it just copies the same number without converting it to a positive number.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
   With Sheets("Sheet1")
      LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LR
   With .Range("W" & i)
      If .Value < 21 Then
         With Range("S2", Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
             .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(iseven(row()),r[1]c,r[-1]c)"
             .Value = .Value
        End With
      End If
   End With
Next i
   End With
```

Comment: Looks like too much `With`ing and looping. In which workbook is the code? Range("S2... could indicate that there are two worksheets. What is <21? You didn't mention any conditions. `For i = 4...` and `With Range("S2,,,`, 2 or 4? Please do clarify. Have you tried `"=if(iseven(row()),-r[1]c,-r[-1]c)"`?

Comment: i should be 2, not 4. Their is only 1 sheet in this workbook, so not sure if the "Range("S2..) is an issue as well. I agree, probably too much withing/looping.

Comment: It's as easy as `.Range("Q2", "S" & LR).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(iseven(row()),-r[1]c,-r[-1]c)"` without a loop, but `<21` and the double last row retrieval are confusing. BTW, great trick with odd/even.